# What is "part technology"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Everything begins with investing in a culture of employee and customer-centricity where ESNs and social networks in general become enablers for a new vision, empowerment, supported by defined outcomes and rewards. Yes, it’s **part technology**. But, tools only take you so far. It’s the philosophy and eventually vision and leadership behind the implementation that serves as the foundation for internal engagement.

What does the phrase in bold mean?

Comment: Reads like a mission statement that got out of control...

Answer (score 1):

I think two different constructions have collided here, producing something that is not quite standard.

One is

> Yes, it's partly technology.

(which is what I think the writer means).

The other is something like

> Yes, it's part technology, part something else.

In that construction, with both elements expressed, "part" is commonly used in this way. But I find it odd used where just one of the elements is expressed.

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, it’s part technology.

This means:

> Yes, part of it (the culture) is technology.

Comment: how can I understand it mean that?